# What needs to be changed in the human cardiovascular system so that he does not die from blood loss or cardiac arrest?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design

What needs to be changed in the device of the human cardiovascular system in order to survive in case of serious blood loss and not die in the event of blocking of vital arteries or cardiac arrest?

So the human heart has two coronary arteries that are not connected to each other.  When one of the arteries is blocked, for example, due to myocardial infarction, the heart tissues associated with it are deprived of oxygen and die.  Dogs and guinea pigs are arranged more perfectly - their arteries are connected and if one fails, the other perfectly performs its function.  Therefore, a dog's heart must be perfect for a person.

However, how else could the human heart and especially the entire cardiovascular system be improved for more efficient blood transport and, which is very important - safety, so that if something happens, my genetically modified person does not die of blood loss ( I need to stop bleeding as quickly as possible ).

Comment: As significant blood loss will always result in death after a time, I feel like you're searching for a certain time frame that someone won't die from blood loss? Could you be more specific in that regard? - reading it again, or something that stops blood loss incredibly quickly in most places?

Comment: I need to stop bleeding as quickly as possible

Comment: Could you split the question in 2? I think these are 2 different questions, requiring 2 different answers.

Comment: Surviving cardiac arrest is *easy* , just apply the same technique you already use to survive decapitation.

Comment: I think it is hard to answer with the hard-science tag, so I will write it as a comment. Organizing the human cardiovascular system as a distributed network with major branch points that can be cut to help survive blood loss seems feasible. You have maximum flow problems with accompanying theorems who deal with these kinds of problems.

Comment: Probably "science based" will be a better tag to use for this kind of question.

Comment: What's wrong with redundancy? (And by definition, *"serious"* blood loss is large enough blood loss to be life threatening. Obviously, if the modified person loses all their blood their will surely die. Which means that whatever you do there will always be a threshold above which blood loss becomes *"serious"*.)

Comment: As mentioned in your later question, [tag:reality-check] and [tag:hard-science] are mutually exclusive and you've not met the mandate for [tag:reality-check].

Answer (score 5):

If we're talking about radical bio-enhancments, here are some ideas:

- Backup/secondary heart. Include a second heart (it can be smaller too) as a backup that normally only really "kicks in" when the person is doing a high intensity activities or the primary heart is damaged.
- Arterial pumps. Get rid of the heart entirely, or make it a "backup" organ. Instead, have all your veins and arteries be heavily muscled and pump blood themselves through timed waves of contractions similarly to how a peristaltic pump works. This way, there is no central organ responsible for moving blood--the function is distributed
- Biological cut-off values. Install many little valves in arteries (and veins) that automatically (or manuallly) shut if pressure loss is detected. When, for example, an arm is cut off, the arteries leading to the shoulder-stump clamp shut to prevent blood loss
- Backup arteries. Layer multiple circulatory systems on top of each other and combine this with the biological cut-off valves. This way, the circulatory system can adapt and re-route bloodflow when injuries are detected.
- Better blood. In normal humans, when the brain stops getting fresh oxygenated blood, it looses consciousness in around 10-30 seconds. Modify your blood to hold more oxygen enabling even reduced flow or temporary pauses to be weathered by stored oxygen
- Ultra fast clotting. Blood already clots and hardens when exposed to air forming scabs and sealing small cuts, but you can edit the blood to do so more aggressively. The moment blood is exposed to open air, it rapidly crystalizes or hardens somehow sealing injuries.

Comment: All of these things help but none reaches the "do not die" of his question.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Death due to blood loss is always caused by some sort of injury causing blood to go somewhere it shouldn't go. All my suggestions either 1) Prevent someone from loosing all their blood to an injury 2) Allow a person to operate with less blood 3) Provide redundancy to the cardiovascular system which includes the function of pumping blood. OP also specifically states that "I need to stop bleeding as quickly as possible" and I feel that my suggestions address this.

Comment: @LorenPechtel These changes would allow the recipient to survive some absurd percentage of traumas that routinely kill people now even when they receive immediate medical attention. Of course it can't save someone dissolved in acid, or those whose heads are removed with cannonball, but it goes about as far as can plausibly be accounted for given the question's constraints.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe an answer within the parameters of your question exists--the circulatory system is life-critical, you can change it to have more redundancy and in other ways be more resistant to failure, but no possible change can get rid of the problem.

Instead, lets modify the body.  The genetic engineers (there's no way this would evolve naturally) add an emergency power system to the cellular structure.  If the cell isn't getting oxygen it falls back onto this to keep itself alive, it ceases to perform any other function other than immune system functions.  Also, remove any adverse reactions to oxygen starvation that you can--I'm thinking specifically of the brain, you can actually survive more than 4 minutes without oxygen, the real killer is swelling when the oxygen is restored.  (There are experiments being done trying rapid cooling for patients who come into the ER in this realm.  I haven't heard of results yet.)

Heart attack, bleed out, asphyxiated?  You drop just like you do now, but instead of the docs having 4 minutes to patch you up they would have hours.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the transition to oxygen already available in the body?

Comment: @FrenchThompson3 I'm not thinking of oxygen.  I'm thinking of a store of energy molecules similar to the normal ones (ATP??), but which are only used for the tasks needed to preserve life.